# Can I take a screen shot of VF page and store into document or attachment?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can I  capture a VF page and  store into document?

I have a visualforce page with capture button. What I want is. When I click on capture  button What ever Information I filled, wanted to save in document.

Is it possible to take screenshot?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you need screenshot exactly? Better option would be converting the page to PDF and storing that as a document.

Comment: Actually if we use pdf then our html element is not rendering properly but without rederedAs="pdf"  page good. So I just thought may be we can capture the image and stored in somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes It is possible. Like @Tushar suggested HTML2Canvas.

Create a page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="sendEmailWithImage">
    <apex:form id="frm">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <div class="container" id="mapDiv">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
        <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 1</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 2</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 3</h3>        
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <button onclick="callActionFunction()">SendEmail</button>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!sendEmail}" name="sendEmailAF" rerender="frm">
        <apex:param assignTo="{!strImageBlob}" name="imageBlob" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            html2canvas(document.body, 
            {
                useCORS: true,
                onrendered: function(canvas) 
                {
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                    document.getElementById("mapDiv").style.display = 'none';
                }
            });
        }
        //
        function callActionFunction()
        {
            sendEmailAF(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].toDataURL());
        }

   </script>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class sendEmailWithImage 
{
    public string strImageBlob {get;set;}

    public void sendEmail()
    {
       Document d = new Document(); d.Name = 'my.png'; 
       String  myContent = 'aabbcc'; 
       d.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(strImageBlob.replaceFirst('data:image/png;base64,','')); 
       d.ContentType = 'image/png';
       insert d;
    }
}
```

Try with this hope this solve your problem.

For more info https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BOh3IAG

Just to help others If they want to send email with image

Just use this controller

```
public class sendEmailWithImage 
{
    public string strImageBlob {get;set;}

    public void sendEmail()
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail =  new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<String> lstString = new List<String>();
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{'enter your email address'});
        mail.setSubject('Email found');
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attach.setContentType('image/png');
        attach.setFileName('Test.png');
        attach.setInline(false);
        attach.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(strImageBlob.replaceFirst('data:image/png;base64,',''));
        mail.setHtmlBody('Please find the attached Image');
        mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach });
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
    }
}
```

Comment: your `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js` expired. instead use this link `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js` Also we need to specify folderId in document . Really Thanks Awesome It work as expected.

Comment: ohh is it sorry for that.  I will update my link. better to store in static resource.